# javascript - Alert when Browser/tab close detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, alert

I have this code that alert when I **click a link** or **refresh** or **close tab**.
But I need alert **only** on **close** window (tab). how to do this?
 I have many external and internal links on my site.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
                var e = e || window.event;
                //IE & Firefox
                if (e) {
                    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
                }
                // For Safari
                 return 'Are you sure?';
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- this will ask for confirmation: -->
       <!-- I need to alert for external links. -->
        <a href="http://google.com">external link</a>


       <!-- this will ask for confirmation: -->
<!-- I don't need to alert for local links in my web site -->
            <a href="about.html">internal link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may call a listener at link-onclick that resets your onbeforeunload listener.

Comment: I can add onclick event to each link that set onbeforeunload to null.but I have many links.

Comment: oh, you mean only onclose, but not when clicking on links ? So I suppose you should add in your example an other "local link" with comments "this one will not ask"

Comment: yes,only alert for onclose and external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.activeElement` is handy in this scenario, it will be equal to the link you click on to unload the page. You can then check the link's `href` attribute whether it contains your host name. An example for codepen.io would be ([demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVGjBO?editors=1010)):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;
  var element = document.activeElement;

  if(element.tagName === 'A' && element.href.indexOf('codepen.io/') === -1) {
    //IE & Firefox
    if (e) {
      e.returnValue = 'Are you sure?';
    }
    // For Safari
    return 'Are you sure?';
  }
};
```

My initial thought was to do a regex for `http://` and `https://` to see if the path is relative but it looks like browsers basically convert relative paths to absolute and prepend the http...

If you want to write this code so that it is more universal you can use `location.hostname` instead of statically typing the hostname to do a comparison on.

Finally, your milage may vary in IE depending on which IEs you want to support the above code might need updated. The trend nowadays is to support IE11+ :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works fine.