# Show confim popup on page unload [DUPLICATED]

Tags: javascript, jquery

recently i am working on a project features that show a confirm box when the user decides to close or refresh the page.

I have done this :

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        return "Are you sure you want leave?";
    };
```

but it's not working on ios chrome/safari browser and does detect only the refresh on chrome android browser.

I have made some research and i found this on MDN web docs

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts
>   created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been
>   interacted with; some don't display them at all. For a list of
>   specific browsers, see the Browser_compatibility section.

anyone have any idea how to deal with this please. 
Thanks.

UPDATE: 
After further research i found my question already answerd here 
[How to make a cross-browser on-window-unload request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317573/how-to-make-a-cross-browser-on-window-unload-request)

Comment: Why are you doing this ? This is a bad practice

Comment: it's not my choice it's a client requirement

Comment: @executable: not always. E.g. when you are editing something and you accidentaly close browser window.

Comment: This question is a potential duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708350/javascript-alert-when-browser-tab-close-detection

Comment: no it's not the post were posted on 2013 and browser spec changed since that

Answer (score 0):

on behalf of @denys séguert :

The short answer is that you can't.

The onbeforeunload event was initially introduced by Microsoft to allow a standard confirmation dialog. It is now supported in the original form by most browsers and in most case a short, non interactive, function is allowed to execute (for example you may log your state in the localStorage). But, as described in the cross-browser jQuery API, this is unreliable :

> The exact handling of the unload event has varied from version to
>   version of browsers. For example, some versions of Firefox trigger the
>   event when a link is followed, but not when the window is closed. In
>   practical usage, behavior should be tested on all supported browsers,
>   and contrasted with the proprietary beforeunload event.

As there are many potential security problems related to the execution of a task when the user asked to end the page (and thus the script), this will probably be unreliable until (and if) a serious normalization effort is done to precise what exactly can be done in a onbeforeunload callback.

For the predictable future, it's recommended to not depend on onbeforeunload but to use other schemes, for example constant background saving or a big "save" button.